# PHP MySQL "DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id` = | unknown column `id`

Tags: php, mysql

**My Code:**

```
if (isset($_POST['del'])) {

  foreach ($_POST['del'] as $id){        
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `̌id` = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    } else {
      printf("Errormessage: %s<br>", $mysqli->error);
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**
`Errormessage: Unknown column '̌‎id' in 'where clause'`

`$_POST['del']` contains integers from checkboxes of a form.

**However, this is used with the same connection earlier, and it works:**

```
$modified = arrayRecursiveDiff($_POST, $data);

foreach($modified as $key => $val_arr) {
  if (!is_array($val_arr)) {continue;}
  foreach ($val_arr as $iteration => $val) {
    $id = $iteration + 1;

    $query = 'UPDATE users
    SET '. $key .'="'. $val .'"
    WHERE id = '. $id;

    if (preg_match('/.*\sdel\=.*/',$query) === 0){
      $mysqli->query($query);
    }
  }
}
```

Funniest thing is that I tried to echo that query and copy it directly into mysql command prompt. It worked perfectly...

I would appreciate if someone had an answer  to what could possibly be going wrong here,

Comment: Are you selecting the the correct database ?

Comment: You are missing a space. WHEREid

Comment: Is that dirt on my screen, or some special character being used as a backtick?

Comment: Change ‎̌id to id, theres a ‎̌ character before the i

Comment: You've got some weird character in there. Looking at your code in EDIT more brought up 2 characters between your backtick `id` --- or is it just me? One of your backticks isn't right, just before `id`

Comment: where is your `$stmt->execute()` ?

Comment: @Zarazthuztra that was just me copying half-asleep. code is valid: fixing that now

Comment: `id` seems to be misspelled with some weird character in it. Retype in your code to fix your problem.

Comment: @MohammadYaseen oh wow, I seem to be pro at undoing to last 'working' state and totally not going far enough. It was there and same result.

Comment: Crazy idea but does your `users` table actually have an `id` column? You sure it's not `user_id` or something else?

Comment: @Phil as I said, copying the produced query into the mysql prompt works. I don't see a reason why suddenly it would be missing.

Comment: @zertap In that case, I suggest you re-edit your question by directly copying the code and error message instead of typing it.

Comment: @zertap Have you confirmed that your connection has also selected the proper db to act on?

Comment: @Zarazthuztra yes, I use the same connection to do some other edits also, which actually work. Let me add them to the question

Comment: @zertap Cool. I'm not trying to insult your abilities or good sense or anything, I just like to make sure we have "everything plugged in" :)

Comment: @Zarazthuztra aha, no worries. I am just very tired at the moment. Been trying to figure this out for hours.

Comment: Are you deleting more than one `id` at a time? By what I can tell by your `foreach ($_POST['del'] as $id){`

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes. The same error message is outputted whether I select only one item or not. Also, I had it without `foreach` but with `implode();` at one point. Still same error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like there's some weird character (*Edit: consult Footnotes*) that resembles a backtick just before `id`, but in fact isn't.

I couldn't tell exactly from my editor, yet. (*Edit: consult Footnotes*)

Change this line:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `‎̌id` = ?")) {
```

to

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?")) {
```

---

### EDIT

I just went into EDIT mode again (11:00 pm EDT) after you edited your question with the updated code and I copy/pasted your query line into my editor, and there is still a strange character between your first backtick and the word `id`.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `‎̌id` = ?")) {
                                                        ^^
```

Copy/paste this actual code in your file. But I'm curious to know **which file editor** you're using that is causing this, or are you typing this by hand?

```
if (isset($_POST['del'])) {

  foreach ($_POST['del'] as $id){        
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    } else {
      printf("Errormessage: %s<br>", $mysqli->error);
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Footnotes:

From what I found in my editor, it seemed to be (*either*) this unicode character `&#8206;` that was before `id`

Unicode hex: 8206
Unicode decimal: 33286
UTF-8 Hex: e88886
HTML Entity: 舆
Source: http://www.htmlescape.net/82/character_8206.html

---

**or this from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark**

I quote: "The LRM causes the punctuation to be adjacent to only LTR text – the "C" and the LRM mark – and hence position as if it were in left-to-right text, i.e., to the right of the preceding text. `&#8206;` or `&lrm;` may be required by some software rather than the invisible Unicode character itself; **the actual invisible character would also make copy editing difficult.**"

**Added note:** The Wikipedia information I found on the subject, I originally found while doing a Google search, which led me to [**this page**](http://www.discogs.com/forum/thread/522aec8bea621161974fae66) which led me to [**The Wikipedia page**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) I posted just above.

---

Another Unicode character that was in the original question was `&#780;`

From [**unicodemap.org**](http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x030C/index.html) and I quote: `"Unicode Character Map - 0x036F (a.k.a. "̌")"`

`Unicode Hexadecimal:   0x030C`
`Unicode Decimal:   780`
`UCS-2 Hexadecimal:     0x0C03`
`UCS-2 Decimal:     3075`
`HTML Hexadecimal:  &#x030C;`
`HTML Decimal:  &#780;`

Character (which may be a bit hard to see):

## ̌

Comment: sorry, that was me somehow hitting wrong buttons while editing it on this site. Same thing for missing execute(); (it is 5:30AM)

Comment: It's ok. I can delete this. @zertap Yet I did retype it myself.

Comment: no, the code still produces the missing column 'id' (and I didn't have that symbol in my original code in the first place)

Comment: Did you reload everything? @zertap and does the `id` column exist? Maybe you named it with the weird `i` character originally, and didn't change the column name.

Comment: Plus, if you're doing this from PHPadmin, you'll need to reload it. @zertap

Comment: If the `id` column exists with an actual letter `i`, that column wouldn't happen to be set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` by any chance, would it? Most of the time, people set `id` columns to that. @zertap

Comment: I have it set to `auto_increment` and afaik `i` in `bind` means that it will expect an integer

Comment: Can you try something and do replace my quotes around `users` and `id` with backticks. SO doesn't format backticks so well in comments. Try using an actual `id` number as a test and try `DELETE FROM 'users' WHERE 'id' = 10` --- #10 being an example number @zertap

Comment: And by the way, I just went into EDIT mode again to copy/paste your query line into my editor, and there is still a strange character between your first backtick and the word `id`. You're not doing something right here, this should be working. @zertap

Comment: certainly interesting... `$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 3");` actually worked

Comment: okay, seems that was actually true. I did double check my code but somehow this tiredness made me miss it still. (Notepad++ didn't disply that combining character at all for some reason). Good thing I got this sorted out. At least I know what to check next time something goes nuts without any clear reason.. thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that we were able to resolve this. Now, get some sleep, it's important. ;-) Cheers @zertap

Comment: `Another Happy Ending`

Comment: oh man, I just edited my question back to match the erroneus stuff too. Ohwell, I guess it doesn't hurt for you to have this here after all the confusing comments.

Comment: Comments can be indeed useful. I think I managed to find what that code was, and inserted it into a footnote at the bottom of my answer. I'm pretty sure that's what it was. @zertap

Comment: Yeah, I know at least the one at bottom was there(and most likely another one too, I just never saw it myself). It is because I have a custom keyboard layout which includes some combining characters as windows doesn't support compose key to make pre-combined characters. Too bad combining characters were invented too late and only work properly in a few places.

Comment: Now we know what the source of the problem was. From what you can see in my **EDIT/footnotes**: *"...the actual invisible character would also make copy editing difficult."* @zertap